# Typescipt Generics - return new instance with same type of generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

Lets say I have an two classes that inherit from some interface: (stripped down for simplicity)

```js
interface IVehicle {}

class Car implements IVehicle { 
    constructor(public color: string) {} 
}
class Helicopter implements IVehicle {}
```

I now have a function which given a instance (which type extends `IVehicle`) will return a new instance of the same type

```js
function clone<T extends IVehicle>(element: T): T {
    if (element instanceof Car) {
        return new Car(element.color);
    }
    ...
    return element;
}

clone(new Helicopter())
```

However I get a error around `return new Car(...)` saying:

```
'Car' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IVehicle'
```

Which seems untrue as the `instanceof` should asset that `T` is of subtype `Car` right?

After that I tried casting the return type to of type `T` with `return new Car(element.color) as T;`.

But this now produces this error:

```
Conversion of type 'Car' to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
```

**And includes** the first error.

Has TypeScript caught a legitimate types issue or is this an error? Am I missing something from the type constraint? How can I fix this error?

Comment: What if `element` extends a `Car` but is not a `Car` itself, then you cannot return `new Car`. Eg: `class BetterCar extends Car {}`.

Comment: @zerkms Ah interesting. I was unaware that `someBetterCarInstance instanceof Car` returned `true`. This would not be an issue for my use case as there are no cases of extending a class than implements `IVehicle` in my codebase. I would guess one fix would be `element.constructor.name === "Car"` but Typescript does not pick up on this? Is there a simple way to safely type this? or is it a case for `// @ts-ignore` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to clone instances of IVehicle, I think adding this operation to the interface itself is a good solution.

```
interface IVehicle<ActualType> {
    clone(): ActualType;
}

class Car implements IVehicle<Car> { 
    constructor(public color: string) {} 
    clone(): Car {
        return new Car(this.color);
    }
}

class Helicopter implements IVehicle<Helicopter> {
    clone(): Helicopter {
        return new Helicopter();
    }
}

const h = new Helicopter();
const hClone = h.clone();
```

**Update**

If you cannot modify source of Vehicles, and subclasses form a closed set, you can use method overloading

```
interface IVehicle {}

class Car implements IVehicle { 
    constructor(public color: string) {} 
}

class Helicopter implements IVehicle {}

function clone(element: Car): Car;
function clone(element: Helicopter): Helicopter;
function clone(element: IVehicle): IVehicle {
    if (element instanceof Car) {
        return new Car(element.color);
    } else if (element instanceof Helicopter) {
        return new Helicopter();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unknown subclass of IVehicle passed to clone " + element)
    }  
}

const h = new Helicopter();
const h1 = clone(h);
```

Comment: Good solution, however if the class declarations are not available to be edited such as being behind a library this refactor isn't possible.